# Unable to fetch 5min candles chart for a custom historic time range

Tags: charts, pine-script, tradingview-api

I can see chart on 5 min timeframe for a period of approx 6 months (whatever maximum number of candles that the chart allows at a time...its approx 6 months data as per my existing plan). But when I 'go to' calendar and put custom time range for some historic time period (time period before last 6 months, say Jan 2022 to June 2022), the chart fails to load. I want to load 5min candles on any custom historic time range (I'm ok with querying 6 months 5min-candles at a time or whatever the max candles allowed). Also I want to know once I load the historic period candle chart of 5min, can I run my custom strategies on this custom time range 5 min candle chart?

I tried changing the custom time range settings (by click the calendar icon at the bottom nav) on a 5 min Nifty chart. The time range selected was that of previous year (time range being 3 months), but the chart never loaded.